# Ansible include_tasks will not run when tags are specified

Tags: ansible

I am including some tasks like shown below in my main.yml (as one of the tasks in a list of several other tasks)

```
- name          : remove swarm
  include_tasks : swarm.undo.yml
  tags          : [ 'never', 'debug' ]
```

when I run the playbook specifying the `--tags never` It just don't run, but shows the output below.

```
PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [node2]
ok: [node4]
ok: [node3]
ok: [node5]
ok: [node1]
ok: [node6]

TASK [swarm : remove swarm] ************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/xbox/Work/Infra/roles/swarm/tasks/swarm.undo.yml for node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, node6

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
node1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node2                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node3                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node4                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node5                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node6                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I do not specify and comment out the other tasks in that group (plus remove the `never` tag). It runs as it should.

Why is this behavior? What should I do to make it run correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour seems normal, and you probably don't have any tasks tagged with `never` in `swarm.undo.yml`.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never) the tags are applicable for tasks and plays. So when you specify `--tags never`, the `include_tasks` (*which is a task*) gets included as expected. But only the tasks inside `swarm.undo.yml` that have the `never` tag will run.

Quoting from the above link:

> Ansible reserves two tag names for special behavior: `always` and `never`. If you assign the `always` tag to a task or play, Ansible will always run that task or play, ...

**Option 1:** So one way is to make sure the relevant tasks in `swarm.undo.yml` have the `never` tag.

**Option 2:** If there are lot of tasks and all should be tagged with `never`, you can consider converting this task file as a playbook (with tag at play level) and use `import_playbook`.

Example `swarm.undo.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: myhosts
  tags:
  - never

  tasks:
  # your tasks go here
```

Then in your `main.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Include swarm undo
  import_playbook: swarm.undo.yml
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I had to tag the tasks inside the file as well.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me on the right path. I've added the needed tag to include tasks and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You should use "apply" keyword, this doesn't work if you write without that one.
The correct syntax (from documentation) is

```
- name: Apply tags to tasks within included file
  include_tasks:
    file: install.yml
    apply:
      tags:
        - install
```

If you want to run all tasks using one tags there is the best way below:

```
- name: Include and run an inner and an outer task
  include_tasks:
    file: install.yml
    apply:
      tags: install
  tags: install
```

Comment: Relevant documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance-for-includes-blocks-and-the-apply-keyword) re. `apply:`

Answer (score 4):

When this changed in Ansible I had to add blocks to all my included files with the relevant tags configured.

However as of Ansible 2.7 you can tell Ansible to apply specific tags to all the included tasks. This means you don't need to make any changes in `swarm.undo.yml`. Your `main.yml` example above would look like this:

```yaml
- name: remove swarm
  include_tasks:
    file: swarm.undo.yml
    # Adds these tags to all included tasks
    tags:  [ 'never', 'debug' ]
  tags: [ 'never', 'debug' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could run with this options to debug:

```
ansible-playbook -i xxx tasks/xx.yml --list-tags
ansible-playbook -i xxx tasks/xx.yml --list-tasks
```

if tags is `all`, all tasks will run

Answer (score 0):

#### Tags `never` and `always`

Are reserved you should not use them. Unless you know what they mean (bellow).

##### About tags on `include_tasks`

You must tag your `include_tasks` with *`always`* on it. To make filtering by tags work. By [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41540#issuecomment-397341326).

```
- name          : my tasks with tags inside
  include_tasks : mytasks.yml
  tags          : [ 'always' ]
```